# Differential equations rewording question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need a little bit of help understanding what a question is asking.
The question is:

Find $ \frac {∂w}{∂r} $ when r = 1 and s = −1

if $ w = (x + y + z)^2 , x = r− s, y = cos(r + s) and z = sin(r + s)$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the expressions for $x,y$ and $z$.

$w=\left(r-s+cos(r+s)+sin(r+s)\right)^2$

Using the chain rule

$\frac{\partial w}{\partial r}= 2 \left(r-s+cos(r+s)+sin(r+s)\right) \cdot \left(    1-sin(r+s)+cos(r+s)\right)$

Now insert the values for $r$ and $s$.

Comment: How did you know to sub into w?

Comment: never mind I can see it now in the question thanks a mill! :)

Comment: Because $x, y$ and $z$ depend on $r$. $w$ can also be written as $w(r)=(x(r)+y(r)+z(r))^2$ You´re welcome.